# Typescript, generics and overloading

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, functional-programming, overloading

I am working on implementing some functions in Typescript that I would like to overload, and which also make use of generics. I am thoroughly confused by this result:

***Note that I have removed code that does not cause the issue**, so please ignore the uselessness of the actual functions.

##### This works:

```
export function persistContactData<T>(
  contactData: T,
  callback?: () => void
): void;
export function persistContactData<T>(
  { contactData }: { contactData: T },
  callback?: () => void
): void;
export function persistContactData<T>(
  { contactData }: { contactData: T },
  callback?: () => void
) {
  // implementation
}
```

##### This does not (only the first has an error):

```
// *** Compile error: "This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation"
//
export function getPersistedContactData<T>(
  contactId: string,
  callback: (result?: T) => void
): void;

// No more errors, and if I remove the above signature everything is fine.
export function getPersistedContactData<T>(
  { contactId }: { contactId: string },
  callback: (result?: T) => void
): void;
export function getPersistedContactData<T>(
  { contactId }: { contactId: string },
  callback: (result?: T) => void
) {
  // implementation
}
```

I am baffled as to what the issue is here, but I am guessing something with how the generic parameter is being used? But it seems like this should not make a difference.

(I am using Typescript 3.9.3)

Edit: I updated without any unknown types

Comment: What is `PersistContactData`?  If it's important, could you give its definition?  If it's not important, could you remove it?  Ideally when your example code is dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link)](https://tsplay.dev/wjJnMw) the only issues present should be the ones you're asking about.

Comment: If I call `getPersistedContactData("foo", x => x);`, what do you expect the `contactId` variable inside the implementation of `getPersistedContactData()` to be?  It won't be a `string`.  The value `"foo"` has no `contactId` property so you're doing something strange.  Not sure what the point of that is, but you should fix it [like this maybe](https://tsplay.dev/wgLZMN)... and if that doesn't help, you might want to elaborate in the question more about what you're trying to do.  Good luck!

Comment: Good point, I have removed all unnecessary and undefined types, so the issue should be easier to see now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the generic parameter is letting the compiler assume that the shape could possibly define the expected type, since the actual implementation will define the actual parameter shapes.

This can be seen if all generics are removed and actual types are used instead.

##### This will work (but probably isn't actually what is intended):

```
export function persistContactData<T>(
  contactData: T,  // <---- What is T?  ┐(￣～￣)┌  Could be the right shape?
  callback?: () => void
): void;
export function persistContactData<T>(
  { contactData }: { contactData: T },
  callback?: () => void
): void;
export function persistContactData<T>(
  { contactData }: { contactData: T },
  callback?: () => void
) {
  // implementation
}
```

##### This will not:

```
// Error
export function persistContactData(
  contactData: string,  // <---- string is not compatible with the implementation
  callback?: () => void
): void;
export function persistContactData(
  { contactData }: { contactData: string },
  callback?: () => void
): void;
export function persistContactData(
  { contactData }: { contactData: string },
  callback?: () => void
) {
  // implementation
}
```